# Open pdf file in app from web

Tags: android, pdf, stream

Is there any way in which I can stream a PDF file in an app activity without downloading it on the phone or tablet?

Sorry i dont have any sample code cause i dont know from where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some samples where PDF file is displayed in an app activity.

You might want to have a look at the site below. ( I haven't tried it yet)

http://www.androidpdf.mobi/

from the website above:

What is PDFViewer 
sample imageAre you looking for a native library to integrate in your own applications? Do you develop Apps on Android, iOS and Windows?

PDFViewer SDK for Mobiles shall help you building better mobile applications. Getting a featured PDF reader with a rich set of professional features will now be a quick and simple procedure.